# GET data by REST endpoint in Azure Data Factory using Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-synapse

I am trying to use REST as a data source for my COPY activity in Data Factory. The DF is working in a Private Network (No public access with the VNET). It gives me an error:

*(("
An error occurred while sending the request.
Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond "")*

I checked everything and compare the public and private network and I found this is 100% private network issue. Maybe its good to mention the REST endpoint is for AZURE MAPS, How we can fix this or more clear how configure the private DF to work with REST?

Answer (score 0):

> *((" An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond "")*

I think these error occurs due to **firewall** issues, Some blocking rules made it **impossible** to access the data source.

1. Check whether you have **enabled for all networks** in firewall and virtual networks.

***Azure portal->storage accounts ->Security + Networking->firewall and virtual networks***

[image]

2. Additionally, use various API testing tools to confirm that your API call is functioning as intended. *you may open a support request for engineers to look into the problem further if it continues.*
3. The Data Factory package started working as soon as the network specialists opened the Firewall between my Integration Runtime server and the target API Url.

***For more in detail you can refer the below documents:***

1. [Troubleshoot Azure Private Endpoint connectivity problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/troubleshoot-private-endpoint-connectivity)
2. [Troubleshoot Azure Data Factory and Synapse Analytics security and access control issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/security-and-access-control-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory#connection-error-in-public-endpoint)